# Fixing plot scale ratios of plots (and then unfixing them again)

Tags: matlab, plot

I have used the function *daspect()* to make the Y and Z axes of a 3-dimensional plot appear with equivalent scale sizes in MATLAB.

I acheived this using the following code (applied after plotting a figure with *plot3*):

```
tmpAspect=daspect(); % get the aspect ratio of the axes scales
daspect(tmpAspect([1 2 2])); % make the Y and Z axes equal in scale
```

This is exactly the behaviour I am looking for, as I need the Y and Z axes to be the same when the figure is initially plotted.

However - if I try to then zoom in, I am only able to zoom whilst maintaining the strict relationship between the Y and Z axes. This is of course exactly what I've asked the program to do, and it's doing its job very well. But I only want this relationship between the Y and Z axes to be applied at the time of generating the plot - after that, it needs to be possible to zoom in any way I like.

Is there a way of setting a plot up with an equivalent scale (as in the code above), but allowing the user to then break this relationship if they want to?

Edit: image below shows three views of my figure. First, in three dimensions, it can be seen that it's useful to maintain a strict relationship between the Y and Z axes (both are in degrees). Second, this is the view of the X and Y axes only. In order to see in more detail (3rd image), it's necessary to zoom in horizontally only. At this point, it's useful to remove the relationship between the Y and Z axes to facilitate better visualisation.

n.b. The Y axis contains the 'X position' data and the Z axis contains 'Y position' data. Just to make things more confusing!

[image]

Comment: how about giving a `axis auto` before zooming?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you would like to be able to zoom. I can't think of any way you could manipulate your 3D plot by zooming, rotating or moving and change the aspect ratio in the process. Just try ti on a plot where you never set `daspect`. The aspect ratio will never change independent of what you do.

Comment: Once I start zooming, I want the axes relationship to be able to be broken. The question is: how could I have the relationship break as soon as the user starts to perform a horizontal or vertical-specific zoom? What I'm looking for is how to detect when the user is trying to zoom in one axis only << if userZooms // axis 'auto'; // end >>; then I can use @Rody's suggestion

Comment: Is it possible you post a a bit of the data you're working with, and detail the desired behavior of your plot a bit (possibly in a few terrifyingly bad MSpaint drawings or so)? Then I'll find you a solution.

Comment: @Rody, images have been added. Hopefully this makes it clearer

Comment: Did you have a chance to look at my solution?

Comment: So I'm guessing you did :) ... now was this indeed what you meant?

Comment: Yep. I've made some tweaks, but that's the function I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here's my first stab at your problem. Approach:

- make a figure, and freeze the aspect ratio as you did before
- if you need XY or XZ projections, just press one of the buttons below the axes

When you press a button, horizontal zooming (e.g., only in x-direction) will be immediately enabled, so scrolling your mouse wheel will then zoom the axes horizontally.

Before diving in, just copy and paste everything into an m-file called `myPlot.m` and execute it. See if this is indeed something along the lines of what you're after. If you're satisfied, I can then spice it up further.

```
function myPlot

    % init figure
    fig = figure;
    set(fig, 'units', 'normalized');

    % some sample data
    datat = 0:200*pi;
    dataz = sin(datat) + rand(size(datat));
    datay = cos(datat) + rand(size(datat));
    datax = datat;

    % sample plot
    plt3D   

    % your current method    
    function plt3D(varargin)
        cleanFig         
        plot3(datax, datay, dataz, 'b.')        
        view(-68, 30)
        tmpAspect = daspect();
        daspect(tmpAspect([1 2 2]));
    end

    % 2D plot, XY projection
    function pltXY(varargin)
        cleanFig
        plot(datax, datay, 'b.')  
        xlabel('Time [msec]')
        ylabel('X-position');
        zoom xon
    end

    % 2D plot, XZ projection
    function pltXZ(varargin)
        cleanFig
        plot(datax, dataz, 'b.')
        xlabel('Time [msec]')
        ylabel('Y-position (^{\circ})');
        zoom xon        
    end

    % draw the buttons
    function pltButtons        

        uicontrol(...
            'parent'  , fig,...
            'style'   , 'pushbutton', ...
            'units'   , 'normalized',...
            'position', [0, 0, 1/3, 1/15], ...
            'string'  , 'plot 3D',...
            'callback', @plt3D);

        uicontrol(...
            'style'   , 'pushbutton', ...
            'units'   , 'normalized',...
            'position', [1/3, 0, 1/3, 1/15], ...
            'string'  , 'plot XY',...
            'callback', @pltXY);

        uicontrol(...
            'style'   , 'pushbutton', ...
            'units'   , 'normalized',...
            'position', [2/3, 0, 1/3, 1/15], ...
            'string'  , 'plot XZ',...
            'callback', @pltXZ);        
    end

    % re-init the figure
    function cleanFig
        set(0, 'currentfigure', fig)
        clf, hold on
        pltButtons
    end 

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if there's an easy way to do. But if everything fails you can create your own zoom callback.

See `doc zoom` for some examples.